# Babel/Jest: Issues exporting default class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Am trying to test the following with [jest](https://jestjs.io/) and am experiencing an issue that looks related to [babel](https://babeljs.io/), specifically, exporting a default class. Consider the following...

```
export default class Test {
  get() {
    return {}
  }
}
```

With a test setup as such...

```
import Test from './test'

describe('test', () => {
  it('should', () => {
    // [...]
  });
});
```

Fails with the following error...

> node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/classCallCheck.js:1
>       ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export
>   default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
>                                                                                                ^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
> ```

---

This is a vue web app. I have the following configuration...

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app', '@babel/env']
};
```

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**'
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '.coverage',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.spec.js'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
};
```

Finally, my test script...

```
// package.json
[...]
"test": "jest"
[...]
```

This is driving my nuts, as all of my `.vue` files and tests work perfectly fine. I am only experiencing issues on some of my core `.js` files that use this above specific syntax.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are you running your tests? I mean what command?

Comment: `$ npm run test`, which invokes `jest` (from package.json snippet at bottom)

Comment: By default, it cannot execute code which has new features like what we have in ES6 and beyond.

Comment: Clearly... Which is exactly why I'm using babel. Anyways, I solved this - needed to remove `@vue/app` preset. Unsure what it was doing, but everything is working now

Comment: Actually, you have to specify that you want to use jest with babel.
See this link: https://babeljs.io/en/setup

Comment: Again, clearly... this is obvious from the `jest.config.js` which is posted in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up removing `@vue/app` as a preset. This seemed inconsequential, as all of my vue testing remained working as expected with `@babel/env`. My Config resulted in the following...

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/env']
};
```

I find this somewhat of an anti-climatic answer. I did not delve into what `@vue/app` may have been doing to cause this observed behavior, but apparently nothing that I need to continue forward.